Map not being set with values returned in a promise
I have a promise which is returning the expected results from an Invokable Method the result is printed to the console as shown below.
[{"noOfCases":103,"OwnerId":"005WU00000412jpYAA"},{"noOfCases":1,"OwnerId":"005WU00000412lYYAQ"}]

I then iterate over the results and add them to a map but the map is empty when logged. I have tried adding the OwnerId to an array and when I log the array the Id's are present.
.then((result) => {
            console.log('Result ' + JSON.stringify(result));

            let m = new Map();
            result.forEach((el) => m.set(el.OwnerId, el.noOfCases));

            console.log('Created Map: ' + JSON.stringify(m));
        })

I need the results in a map because I will be using the OwnerId to retrieve the number of cases for each owner and update the UI
A work around may be to iterate over the results and just check the OwnerId of the current user in the array but this is not good code or efficient.

The Map object doesn't like to JSON.stringify. See this Stack Overflow Q&A. Basically, JSON.stringify treats a Map as a normal Object, and doesn't know how to serialize the key-value pairs. That said, you can use a plain object for this:
let mappedData = Object.fromEntries(
  result.map(entry => ([entry.OwnerId, entry.noOfCases])
);


This is because for Javascript's Map has no
No native support for serialization or parsing. -MDN Doc

Quote from here
This is why when you console.log the Map after JSON.stringify, its returning an empty object. According to the official documentation, you can stringify the Javascript Map, by looking into this Stack Overflow post.
However, if you want to show the noOfCases based on the OwnerId, then you can create a Javascript object. In this object, you can user OwnerId as key and noOfCases as value. So when you access the OwnerId property, it returns the noOfCases.
For example:
let m = {};
result.forEach((el) => m[el.OwnerId] = el.noOfCases);

now you can access the property like this;
m['005WU00000412jpYAA'] //which will return 103

